# Set the New Item Link to choose between available forms

Tags: 2013, document-library, content-type, form, ootb

## Objective

I'd like to change the functionality of the **New Item** button for a Document Library. Right now if you click the button, it simply prompts you to upload a document. I want it to provide the user with a list of available choices (the two forms I've created in InfoPath).

I need the solution to be an OOTB one as it needs to be able to be replicated by those who are not so savvy in the ways of SharePoint.

### What I have

- SharePoint 2013
- Site Owner Level Permissions
- 2 Forms Published as Content Types

### What I don't have

- Server Side Access

#### Current

Right now my forms are only accessible by going to the **Files** tab and select the arrow under **New Document**. While instructions are provided to follow those steps to access the forms, it would be nice to simply use the **New Item** button provided.

Answer (score 0):

As list forms are just .aspx pages, you will need to redirect user to one of these pages (like .../list/forms/newform1.aspx, and .../list/forms/newform2.aspx).

I would add Script Editor Web Part to the page, and inside it something like (requires jQuery):

```
<div id="myFormSelector" style="display:none;">
  <ul><li onclick="location.href='/site/list/forms/form1.aspx'">Form 1</li>
  <li onclick="location.href='/site/list/forms/form1.aspx'">Form 2</li></ul>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#idHomePageNewItem").attr("onclick", "$('#myFormSelector').show(); return false;" );
});
</script>
```

You will also want to position the opened DIV below the New Item button, that can be done with absolute positioning or using some JS like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666367/how-do-i-position-a-div-relative-to-the-mouse-pointer-using-jquery).

Comment: Hmm. I like your ideas, however I'm unsure the best method to actually do those things. Would it be possible for you to go in a little more depth on how to actually do some of these things?

Comment: Re-read your question, and updated answer, as it was _not_ the Ribbon you were asking about, sorry.